# java.lang.VerifyError on Android Studio 3.2 Upgrade

Tags: android

I've looked around and tried to clean my build folders, invalidate cache & restart, and set `android.enableR8=false`

But I still can't get past this issue when I build a release apk and try running the app.

```
2018-09-26 23:07:19.428 19200-19200/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sic.nzb.app, PID: 19200
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp: void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>() failed to verify: void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(): [0x33] register v1 has type Uninitialized Reference: java.lang.Object Allocation PC: 49 but expected Reference: java.lang.Object
     void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions) failed to verify: void com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions): [0x4B] 'this' arg must be initialized (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.a(SourceFile:274)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(SourceFile:37)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:31)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'


implementation project(':oIFileManager')
implementation project(':FullScreenActivity')
implementation rootProject.ext.libraries.appcompatv7
implementation rootProject.ext.libraries.supportdesign
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
implementation project(path: ':unrar-native')
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android'

implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'
testImplementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

}

Comment: could you add the `dependencies` from the module's `build.gradle`, please?

Comment: Added. I noticed if I disable minify, app will run. is this a proguard issue?

Comment: difficult to tell with all the variables being pulled in; the crashlytics possibly should be migrated. how you initialize that FirebaseApp ?? there might not be a context class being passed.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to build failing with specific android gradle plugin, 3.2.0 fails but 3.1.0 works

Comment: I initialize it with     Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); in onCreate

Comment: Same proplem here. If I use `proguard-rules-optimize.txt` the `VerifyError` can occur everywhere, but with `proguard-rules.txt` everything is ok. `android.enableR8=false` also can not help me. For now I have to revert to previous `3.1.4` to get all working again

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113798060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by updating proguard-project.txt

FROM:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
*;
```

}

TO:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your older firebase dependencies is being referenced and there must be some changes related to classes which cause the "VerifyError". So, you need to delete your `.gradle` folder under your home directory, e.g. `~/.gradle` for Linux or macOS, as well as the `.gradle` under your **project root directory**. Also, try to delete all the cached `.m2` folders under your home dir `~/` as well.

Comment: Tried this and it did not help